# Understanding RewriteCond in .htacces files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm having problems understanding how RewriteCond directive works. So far, it's pretty clear that it compares to strings to apply a RewriteRule. I have this file:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php
</IfModule>
```

This works for me but I don't know why it works. So far in the RewriteCond directive I understand:

> *if the value of REQUEST_FILENAME is NOT a file in the hard drive then allow the rule*

This doesn't have sense becouse app_dev.php after substituting is a file in the hard drive. Anyways, could someone enlighten me with this issue? I am having a very harsh time figuring out how this works.

Answer (score 2):

If you requested `/styles/main.css` then that *would* be a file on the filesystem and the RewriteRule would not be processed.  Apache would simply serve the file.

If you request `/foo/bar` and that does not exist, the RewriteRule is processed and the request becomes `/app_dev.php` however, PHP still has access to the original URL, before the rewrite took place.  By using that, a framework such as symfony can serve different pages for different URLs, even though the PHP file is the same one every time.

Comment: ok I see, then what is the value of %{REQUEST_FILENAME}? If I requested the resource /foo/bar the value of %{REQUEST_FILENAME} will be /foo/bar? I don't understand what value is stored in %{REQUEST_FILENAME}

Answer (score 1):

It's the actual file path on your actual filesystem.

So if your `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www` and you request `/styles/main.css`, then when used in directory/htaccess context `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is `/var/www/styles/main.css` - and the `!-f` is checking if that file exists and letting the `RewriteRule` occur if it does not exist.

Note that it behaves differently and won't have the document root included if it's not used in a directory/htaccess context, as explained in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> REQUEST_FILENAME
>
> The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI.